# Oracle SQL - getting value based on a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables:

```
TR_TRN (ID_WS, STORE, STATUS)
TR_RTL (ID_WS, STORE, ID_LY)
```

The status in TR_TRN is either 19 or 20.

Some records have both the statuses 19 and 20.
and some have only 19 (meaning that they are pending transactions)

the two tables are joined with:

```
ID_WS and STORE
```

I need all the records from TR_RTL that has only the status of 19 in the TR_TRN table.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS()` and use the `HAVING` clause in the inner query to determine if this record has only `status = 19` with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT * FROM TR_RTL t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TR_TRN s
             WHERE s.id_ws = t.id_ws and s.store = t.store
             HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN s.status = 19 THEN 1 END) = 1
                AND COUNT(CASE WHEN s.status = 20 THEN 1 END) = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all ID's (ID_WS, STORE) that have status 19 and don't have status 20 use the following query

```
select ID_WS, STORE from TR_TRN where STATUS = 19
minus
select ID_WS, STORE from TR_TRN where STATUS = 20;
```

The rest is a simple IN subquery select:

```
select * from TR_RTL 
where (ID_WS, STORE) IN
(
select ID_WS, STORE from TR_TRN where STATUS = 19
minus
select ID_WS, STORE from TR_TRN where STATUS = 20
);
```